# Existence of vector for which $Av\neq 0$ if $A\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{F})$. If $A\neq 0$ why does it follow that there exists a vector $v\in\mathbb{F}^n$ such that $Av\neq 0$?

I tried arguing by contrapositive, or by considering rank and nullity but didn't reach far.

Comment: Suppose that $Av=0$ for every $v \in \Bbb F^n$. Then, if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the canonical base of $\Bbb F^n$, $Ae_j=0$ for every $j=1,\dots,n$. (Note that $Ae_j$ is precisely the $j$-th column of $A$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of $A$ are the images of the basis vectors of $\Bbb{F}^n$. So if $\forall v\in \Bbb{F}^n,Av=0$, all the columns of $V$ are null vectors and $A=0$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that matrices represent linear transformations between vector spaces. So if two matrices map every possible input to the same output, they represent the same transformation on the same basis, and therefore must be the same matrix.

The zero matrix sends any input to zero, so if $A$ sent every possible input to zero, it must be equal to the zero matrix. So, by contrapositive, if $A$ is nonzero, there must exist some vector which is not mapped to the zero vector.